# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null MongoDb error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm

Getting a mongodb error on a query. Here the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Here's the code:

```
// Open a connection with MongoDB

MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, (error, db) => {
  let dbo = db.db('gamblenomore');

//Running a query to find all customers that are in timezone CST.

dbo.collection('customers').find({therapyConfirmation: true, therapyTimeZone: 'CST', therapyDay: { $gt: 0 } }).toArray((error, result) => {
    let max = result.length;
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
```

There are no documents currently in `'customers'` with the above criteria.

Comment: You should check for errors before you try to use `result`

Comment: I must be going crazy, the error is no longer there when i redeployed in heroku any thoughts, i changed nothing besides what you suggested:
dbo.collection('customers').find({therapyConfirmation: true, therapyTimeZone: 'CST', therapyDay: { $gt: 0 } }).toArray((error, result) => {
         if (error) {
          throw error;
        }
let max = result.length;

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
dbo.collection('customers').find({
  therapyConfirmation: true,
  therapyTimeZone: 'CST', 
  therapyDay: { $gt: 0 } 
}).toArray((error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    let max = result.length;
    // some other code
});
```